# WooCommerce Rest API, always return 10 results

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-rest-api

I tried to get all products (17) by woocommerce rest API:

```
require_once('WooCommerce/vendor/autoload.php');

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://***', 
    'ck_***', 
    'cs_*'
);

$results = $woocommerce->get('products', [], ['per_page'=>17]); 

var_dump($results);
```

But returns 10 results.

Please advice what is wrong?

We have 17 active products on our woocommerce website.

Answer (score 0):

> If you see the [WooCommerce PHP lib doc](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php), you have to make request
>   like this `$woocommerce->get($endpoint, $parameters = [])`.

So you code should be

```
//...
$results = $woocommerce->get('products', ['per_page'=>17]); 
//...
```

Ref: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#parameters

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this code but returns 10 results:
```array (size=1)
  'products' => 
    array (size=10)```

Comment: which WooCommerce API version you are using?

Comment: default version is v3